# How to get system environment variables via gulp?

Tags: linux, gulp, environment-variables

I am just wondering how I can get system environment variables from gulp task.  I know you can get process environment variables via `process.env.NODE_ENV`, however, I would like to get system environment variables.  For example, when I export one to my system like so: `export MY_UN='username'` I want to be able to access `MY_UN` from my gulp script via a task or whatever.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this was a stupid question, and i realized i messed up on my side.  I was wondering why i couldnt get my system environment variable from `process.env`.  Well, its because I forgot to source my `.profile` file.  I am able to get system environment variables now.  Please excuse my Idiocracy.